# QML - How to stop inherits properties of parent element to ListView items?

Tags: qt, listview, inheritance, properties, qml

I have ListView element containing Item with properties, but this ListView element underlying in some custom element where I have property alias from Label element. By some reason Item reads this property from custom parent element and not from this Item itself, how can I stop this behaviour and let Item read property from itself first if such defined?

As you can see I have following logic:

- Menu Items is just an QML `Item`
- Menu is ListView element which one inherit childrens using following default property alias `default property alias contents: addItem.children`
- Custom element contains Menu with name `__menu` which one inherits children items from parent (custom element) using this default property alias `default property alias contents: addItem.children`

It looks like something wrong in this logic because I need to use `fontFamily` property different for each element as described in `main.qml` but menu items inherit this property from parent custom element, is there a way I can use same name for this property and use custom font when I need and inherit parent element font if property is not set?

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import "breezequick"

BreezeQuickApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    palette: mainPalette
    BreezeQuickPalette {
        id: mainPalette
        theme: "dark"
    }
    BreezeQuickMenuBar{
        id: menuBar
        palette: mainPalette
        title: "Breeze Quick"
        fontFamily: "Ubuntu"
        BreezeQuickMenuItem{
            title: "Item 1"
            fontFamily: "Ubuntu-Italic"
        }
        BreezeQuickMenuItem{
            title: "Item 2"
            fontFamily: "Ubuntu-Bold"
        }
        BreezeQuickMenuItem{
            title: "Item 3"
        }
    }

}
```

Item element:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item {
    id: root
    property string title: "Menu Element"
    property string fontFamily: "Ubuntu"
    property string iconSource
    signal trigerred()
}
```

Menu element:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
    id: root
    property int dpi: Screen.pixelDensity
    property BreezeQuickPalette palette: BreezeQuickPalette
    property alias currentIndex: menuList.currentIndex
    property alias currentItem: menuList.currentItem
    property alias count: menuList.count
    property alias model: menuList.model
    property bool boldCurrentItem: false
    default property alias contents: addItem.children
    property bool autoHideMenu: true
    property int fontSize: 16
    property int __menuHeight
    property int __menuWidth
    property int __maxWidth
    anchors.fill: parent
    opacity: 0
    property int __menuX
    property int __menuY
    focus: visible
    visible: opacity > 0
    function show(x,y){
        __updateSize()
        opacity = 1
        if (x) {wrapper.x = x} else if (__menuX) {wrapper.x = __menuX} else {wrapper.x = 72}
        if (y) {wrapper.y = y} else if (__menuY) {wrapper.y = __menuY} else {wrapper.y = 72}
    }
    function hide(){
        opacity = 0
    }
    function __updateSize(){
        var i=0
        for (var child in menuList.contentItem.children){
            ++i
            if (i == 1){
                __maxWidth = menuList.contentItem.children[child].width
            } else if (i != 1) {
                if (menuList.contentItem.children[child].width > __maxWidth) {
                    __maxWidth = menuList.contentItem.children[child].width
                }
            }
        }
        for (child in menuList.contentItem.children){
            menuList.contentItem.children[child].width = __maxWidth
        }
    }
    Behavior on opacity {
        NumberAnimation{
            duration: 150
        }
    }
    Item {
        id: addItem
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: wrapper
        color: palette.alternateBackground
        implicitWidth: if (!__menuWidth) {
                           __maxWidth
                       } else {
                           __menuWidth
                       }
        implicitHeight: if (!__menuHeight) {
                            if (menuList.count > 0 ) {
                                menuList.contentItem.children[0].height*menuList.count
                            } else {
                                dpi*19
                            }
                        } else {
                            __menuHeight
                        }
        ListView{
            id: menuList
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: contents
            delegate: menuElement
            flickableDirection: Flickable.AutoFlickDirection
            z: parent.z + 1
            clip: true
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        }
        z: parent.z + 100
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: shadow
        anchors {
            left: wrapper.left
            top: wrapper.top
            leftMargin: dpi
            topMargin: dpi
        }
        opacity: 0.4
        color: palette.shadeBlack
        width: wrapper.width
        height: wrapper.height
    }
    MouseArea{
        id: screenArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: hide()
    }
    Component {
        id: menuElement
        Rectangle {
            property bool isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem
            id: menu
            color: palette.alternateBackground
            height: menuText.font.pixelSize*2.7
            width: menuText.width + menuIcon.width + 12*dpi
            Image {
                id: menuIcon
                anchors{
                    verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    left: parent.left
                    leftMargin: 2*dpi
                }
                height: menuText.height
                width: height
                sourceSize.width: menuIcon.width
                sourceSize.height: menuIcon.height
                z: menuText.z
                source: iconSource
            }
            Text {
                id: menuText
                anchors{
                    verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    left: menuIcon.right
                    leftMargin: 2*dpi
                }
                text: title
                font.family: fontFamily
                color: palette.normalText
                font.pointSize: fontSize
                font.bold: boldCurrentItem ? isCurrentItem : false
                z: parent.z + 1
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: highlight
                anchors {
                    fill: parent
                }
                opacity: (menuElementArea.pressed) ? 1 : 0
                color: palette.focusColor
                Behavior on opacity {
                    NumberAnimation {
                        duration: 100
                    }
                }
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: menuElementArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {
                    menuList.currentIndex = index
                    if (autoHideMenu) {
                        hide()
                    }
                    menuList.model[index].trigerred()
                }
                z: parent.z + 2
            }
        }
    }
    Keys.onReleased: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Back) {
            if (visible){
                event.accepted = true
                hide()
            }
        }
        if (event.key === Qt.Key){

        }
    }
}
```

Custom element containing Menu and which inherit Menu Items:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
    property int dpi: Screen.pixelDensity
    property alias title: textTitleField.text
    property alias fontFamily: textTitleField.font.family
    id: root
    implicitWidth: parent.width
    implicitHeight: textTitleField.height*2.7
    property bool menuHighlightEnabled: true
    default property alias contents: __menu.contents
    property BreezeQuickPalette palette: BreezeQuickPalette
    BreezeQuickPalette{
        id: __palette
        theme: palette.theme
    }
    signal menuClicked()
    Rectangle {
        id: bar
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: palette.alternateBackground
        BreezeQuickMenuButton{
            id: menuButton
            highlightEnabled: true
            palette: __palette
            anchors {
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                right: parent.right
            }
            onClicked: {
                menuClicked()
                __menu.show()
            }
            height: parent.height
        }
        Text {
            id: textTitleField
            text: qsTr("Menu Bar ...")
            font.pointSize: 18
            font.bold: true
            color: __palette.paperWhite
            anchors {
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                left: parent.left
                leftMargin: 16
            }
        }
    }
    BreezeQuickMenu{
        id: __menu
        palette: __palette
        parent: root.parent
        __menuX: root.x + root.width - menuButton.width/3 - __menu.__maxWidth
        __menuY: root.y + menuButton.height/4
    }
}
```

As you can see on picture font still same as on title bar:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that there are no font families named "Ubuntu-Bold" and "Ubuntu-Italic". You should use the font.bold and font.italic properties in your Text elements instead to make your text bold or italic.

Comment: thanks for answer, actually I loaded necessary fonts from BreezeQuickApplicationWindow element, will update question later

Answer (score 0):

Well, found quick solution for this. Created font property and assigned to each item, so for now it's possible to set different fonts and parameters for each Item and MenuBar title. But anyway to call it different names.

Menu Item:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item {
    id: root
    property string title: "Menu Element"
    property string fontFamily: "Ubuntu"
    property string iconSource
    property font itemFont
    signal trigerred()
}
```

Application Window:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("BreezeQuick")
    property BreezeQuickPalette palette: BreezeQuickPalette

    style: ApplicationWindowStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            color: palette.alternateBackground
        }
    }

    signal loaded()

    Component.onCompleted:
        loaded()

    FontLoader {
        source: "qrc:/resources/fonts/ubuntu.ttf"
    }
    FontLoader {
        source: "qrc:/resources/fonts/roboto.ttf"
    }
    FontLoader {
        source: "qrc:/resources/fonts/oxygen.ttf"
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import "breezequick"

BreezeQuickApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    palette: mainPalette
    BreezeQuickPalette {
        id: mainPalette
        theme: "dark"
    }
    BreezeQuickMenuBar{
        id: menuBar
        palette: mainPalette
        title: "Breeze Quick"
        titleFont {
            family: "OxygenMono-Regular"
            bold: true
            pointSize: 20
        }
        BreezeQuickMenuItem{
            title: "Item 1"
            itemFont{
                family: "Roboto-Regular"
                bold: false
                pointSize: 16
            }

        }
        BreezeQuickMenuItem{
            title: "Item 2"
            itemFont{
                family: "Ubuntu"
                bold: false
                pointSize: 16
            }
        }
        BreezeQuickMenuItem{
            title: "Item 3"
            itemFont{
                family: "OxygenMono-Regular"
                bold: false
                italic: true
                pointSize: 16
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well for now it's possible to use different fonts, but anyway it's just workaround.

[image]